# Separate code in single Form [C#]

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a WinForm application with separate groupboxes and objects, but the code isn't sorted by groupbox and pretty messed up.

Can the code be split in 2 files or something with the objects on the same place?

EDIT:

this is my code:

[image]

how should i split it? 
(i need everything with News and everything with Dir changed)

Comment: Not clear on what you mean by "the code isn't sorted by groupbox"... can you elaborate?

Comment: Not literally in groupboxes. Ive got 2 sets of objects, but I want to separate the code for each set of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find it easier and less problematic to use regions than trying to split out the files:

```
#region -  TextBox Events  -

private void txtNews_TextChanged() {...}

private void txtDir_TextChanged() {...}

#endregion

#region -  ComboBox Events  -

private void cmbNews_SelectedIndexChanged() {...}

private void cmbDir_SelectedIndexChanged() {...}

#endregion
```

which, when collapsed, looks like

```
-  TextBox Events  -

-  ComboBox Events  -
```

You could also consider a tool like Ora to navigate large files:  http://ora.codeplex.com/  JetBrains' Resharper also has an excellent file-structure viewer.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me like you want to check out [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=VS.100).aspx).

They allow you to split the code for a single class between multiple files.

Comment: Forms are already partial classes.  Adding yet another part to it is a great way to break the designer.

Comment: @Hans: That won't break the designer.

Comment: @SLaks: try it, add an event handler and move it to the extra partial.  Note how the designer no longer sees it and will readily add another.

Comment: @Hans:  You are right about the FooForm.designer.cs file, but for separating your own functions/logic, there is no reason not to add more files.  VS correctly navigates to the correct file when you select from the member/method drop down in the code window.  (Up through VS2008 at least.  Not fortunate enough to work with VS2010 yet :)

Comment: Separating your own functions would work fine, but it looks like the OP is trying to clean up the events.  Which will definitely run into the issues Hans is describing.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably put each GroupBox into a separate UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Split the codebehind into extra parts, beyond what the designer sets up for you so it can keep its code "safe".
- Create a user control for each GroupBox, possibly even the same object set up with different names and contained controls.
- Just rearrange the handlers for controls by GroupBox within the single codebehind, extracting lines from common methods (Bind/Unbind-type behavior) into groupbox-specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can create partial classes, if you want more than one code file.  It looks like:

```
public partial class MyClass {...}
```

You can, optionally, add a `DependentUpon` property in the .csproj (I don't know of a way to do this other than manually edit the .csproj).  This joins them together in the IDE.  It looks like:

```
<Compile Include="MyClass.Controls.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MyClass.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

I'm a little worried that you're talking about the auto-generated code in the .designer.cs file... you don't want to change anything that VS generated for you... if you do, you will lose all your changes the next time you change something on the form, because VS will regenerate it!